# Cannot edit style.css from admin panel, because the template is looking for style.min.css

Tags: templates, css

I am trying to edit the style.css file for a [Wordpress theme](http://alienwp.com/themes/origin/), however the changes I make (via admin or ftp) are not reflected on the site because that is using style.min.css. It is very cumbersome manually minifying the css everytime I make small edits. I'd also like to be able to make quick changes in the admin Editor GUI.

What would be the practice practice to do this? Should not style.min.css be auto-generated?

Comment: I thought this would be a case of hooking the 'styles.css updated' event in your theme functions when in admin mode, and then running the minify task (carefully, w.r.t. filesystem access) but there isn't an event: neither on [the save](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0-branch/wp-admin/theme-editor.php#L87) nor the [update notification](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.0-branch/wp-admin/theme-editor.php#L125) :-( There's an event for practically everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to use a [child](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) [theme](http://kovshenin.com/2014/child-themes-import/) instead.

A plugin like [Simple Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) is another option.

Two alternate quick fixes:

1. Disable the filter that selects `style.min.css` by commenting out this line in `origin/library/function/styles.php`:

   `add_filter( 'stylesheet_uri', 'hybrid_min_stylesheet_uri', 10, 2 );`
2. Delete `style.min.css` :)

There is no auto-generation of minified files within WordPress.